# why uvicorn port 80 options works on another port?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, asgi

I tried fastApi and uvicorn.

But I'm wondering why when i execute uvicorn in port 80, it works on port 52384.
52384 shows the api response but 80 does not.

in the dockerfile, I added `EXPOSE 80 80`.

```
// terminal
vscode ➜ /app (master ✗) $ lsof -i:80
vscode ➜ /app (master ✗) $ uvicorn main:app --port 80
INFO:     Started server process [1115]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52384 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

```py
// python 
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `127.0.0.1:52384` is the source address of the request (client address), and the destination port is 80. Ports for outgoing requests are usually chosen randomly from the dynamic range, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

Comment: thansk! I understood!